# Can't figure out how to limit result to one hopefully using .group

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a drop-down to filter results in a table. So far everything is working except that multiple items are being listed.

Such as:

```
Clec ID:
216 324
216 315
```

Where as I only want one 216.

```
    <select name="by_clecid">
      <option value="">All</option>
      <% @task_queues.each do |task_queue| %> <option value="<%= task_queue.clecid %>"><%= task_queue.clecid %></option><% end %> 
    </select>
```

I thought I could use a .group but not exactly sure how to use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated I am not very familiar with Ruby.

EDIT:
The model:

```
class TaskQueue < ActiveRecord::Base

  require 'task_queue'

  self.table_name = "taskqueue"
  belongs_to :clec_profile
  scope :by_status,     -> status  { where(:status => status) }
  scope :by_tasktype,   -> tasktype  { where(:tasktype => tasktype) }
  scope :by_clecid,     -> clecid  { where(:clecid => clecid) }
  scope :by_taskid,     -> taskid  { where(:taskid => taskid) }
  scope :by_hostname,     -> hostname  { where(:hostname => hostname) }

  def elapsed_seconds
    case status
    when "Completed"
      finishtime - starttime
    when "Pending"
      Time.now - starttime
    when "Waiting", "Failed"
      0
    end
  end

end
```

Some of the controller:

```
class TaskQueuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task_queue, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  has_scope :by_status, :by_tasktype, :by_taskid,  :by_hostname, :by_clecid

  def index
    @task_queues = apply_scopes(TaskQueue).all
    @task_queues = @task_queues.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  end
end
```

EDIT:
 Here's a picture to better show what is happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdMB8.png
I would show it as an image but not enough rep yet.

Comment: That is for the html Clec ID lists 216 more than twice since it is being pulled from a database, I was just using that as an example. I'm looking for a way to use ruby to only pull it if it's not already present. From what I know the method .group should work, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: @ArupRakshit he wrote that as one is the option value and the other is the actual text being spit out in the option list.

Comment: Show the code where you are pulling the data and we can help you modify it there so it is unique.  Alternatively, if this is an array, you can just use .uniq on it.  It would definitely help to see the controller and/or model code for @task_queues

Comment: @emcanes Added the model and the important part of the controller. I added the .uniq to: task_queues.uniq.each do |task_queue|  but it still displayed all the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides the `uniq` method for generating a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` query. You could for example do

```
@clec_ids = apply_scopes(TaskQueue).uniq.pluck(:clecid)
```

if you want to re-use the already selected `@task_queues`, you could use the cousin method `Array#uniq` to ensure only unique `clecid`s are displayed

```
@clec_ids = @task_queues.map(:clecid).uniq
```

In your view you would then do

```
<select name="by_clecid">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <% @clec_ids do |clec_id| %>
    <option value="<%= clec_id %>"><%= clec_id %></option>
  <% end %> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your examples really helped and it's working now . It's crazy how long you can spend on the little things

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring a few code smells here for a moment, what you're really wanting to do is pull just a list of possible `clec_id` values from the database. For that, `ActiveRecord` offers `pluck`:

```
@clec_ids = ClecProfile.pluck(:id) #=> [1,2,3,4,5,...]

# alternately...
@clec_ids = TaskQueue.clec_profiles.pluck(:id).uniq #=> [1,2,3,4,5,...]
```

The reason `uniq` isn't working for you now, I believe, is that you're looking at multiple association objects that aren't unique, just their ids. Using `pluck` to get an array of ids instead of instantiated ActiveRecord objects sidesteps the issue.

Comment: Oh trust me I know there's tons of code smells. Thanks for the answer I learn so much about ruby every day.